# How to deal with "Resource id #XXX" (LongBlob) in Angular?

Tags: angular, symfony

It's been many days from now that I'm trying to display a Blob (image storred in my database) in my Angular project (Angular 10.0.7).

I have a REST API in Symfony 4.3.11 and it works well.

The Blob in my database (MySQL) is encoded in Base64, the type is, to be precised, LONGBLOB. I tried to decode it using online WebSite and that's working, I have my image back.

That problem is that when I run my request, I get :

```json
"image": "Resource id #788",
```

My Entity in Symfony is :

```php
    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="IMAGE", type="blob", length=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;
```

I have tried to replace the type with `"text"` or `"string"` but I get this error :

```json
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Your data could not be encoded because it contains invalid UTF8 characters."
}
```

On the Angular side I have this when I try to print the image in my Browser :

```html
<img _ngcontent-shg-c116="" src="unsafe:data:image/png;base64,Resource id #788">
```

That's seem legit because my request returned this string...

How to deal with this on my Angular ? Or do I have to change my request ? And if so, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blob` doctrine type return [resource](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/types.html#blob) so you can try at your entity something like:

```php
private string $imageBase64;

public function getImageBase64(): ?string
{
    if (null === $this->image) {
        return null;
    }

    if (!isset($this->imageBase64)) {
        $data = stream_get_contents($this->image);
        fclose($this->image);
        $this->imageBase64 = base64_encode($data);
    }

    return $this->imageBase64;
}
```

Comment: Where do I have to write this ? Because it seems like my Request doesn't care about my Entity, like I have tried to delete all Getters & Setters and it still returns me everything. I have only one Entity and Controller so I don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

I have made some more research, but still can't figure out how to deal with this type.

But, here's what I found :

- On W3school :

```
PHP Resource
The special resource type is not an actual data type. It is the storing of a reference to functions and resources external to PHP.

A common example of using the resource data type is a database call.

We will not talk about the resource type here, since it is an advanced topic.
```

- On Doctrine-Project (thanks to shyv's answer) :

```
blob

Maps and converts binary string data without a maximum length. 
If you don't know the maximum length of the data to be stored, you should consider using this type. 
Values retrieved from the database are always converted to PHP's resource type or null if no data is present.
```